# DataGridView и смена DataSource в процессе выполнения

Tags: .net, visual-basic

Наполняю ArrayList экземплярами одного и того же класса (назовем его Product), и ассоциирую его с DataGridView.DataSourсe.

```
arrlProducts = New ArrayList  
arrlProducts.Add(product)  
arrlProducts.Add(product1)  
dtgrw.DataSource = arrlProducts
```

В самой таблице задано нужное форматирование ячеек, столбцы забиндены на свойства Product. Все красиво. 
Но по ходу выполнения список изменяется - из него удаляют или добавляют элементы, и потому нужно обновить таблицу.
Пробовал переопределить свойство DataSource - все равно отображается все по-старому.
Попробовал так:

```
dtgrw.DataSource = Nothing  
dtgrw.DataSource = arrlProducts
```

Таблица обновилась в соответствии со списком, но снесла все настройки столбцов таблицы - шрифт, названия столбцов, повставляв столбцы на основе свойств Product.
Как правильно обновлять таблицу, если обновился источник данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для автоматической синхронизации отображения с коллекцией рекомендуется использовать коллекции, реализующие IBindingList. Обычно это DataView или BindingList<t>

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам.
Надо было выставить опцию
    dtgrw.AutoGenerateColumns = False